# Where do I get motion detector for ardruino that can actually be installed in ceiling?

Tags: arduino-yun

This might be a bit of off topic but I have nowhere else to go. :-) I have programmed motion detection with ardruino and would like to integrate it with my home automation system.

Would like to install the PIR in the ceiling of the entrance.

The problem is that all low voltage PIRs for ardruino are sold without any case (just a board).

Does it mean I have to buy a regular PIR (with relay integrated) and modify it?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to modify it?

Comment: I bought a regular PIR (with 220V relay) and as I remember well motion detection board needs higher voltage than what ardruino can supply 3.3V and 5V.

Comment: So supply it with that higher voltage then.

Comment: I would rather avoid it but it looks like there is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be quite the answer you were looking for, but...

3D print your case.

I expect you haven't got a 3D printer but you can find someone on [3D hubs](http://www.3dhubs.com/) to print it for you, and you might not even have to design the case because [thingiverse has a few already](http://www.thingiverse.com/search?q=pir%20sensor&sa=)...

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at Alarm PID units, they typically will operate on 12VDC and have a relay output contact and a tamper contact.  They are not that expensive and come with a case.

Gil